# where to use the client ID and secret in apple sign in

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, apple-sign-in

I have created a mobile app with Apple Sign in using Objective C. Im confused on where to use my client ID and client secret key since I already got the authorization code and id token by following this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple
and converting it to Objective C.

Comment: The same question...Did you find an answer?